# Eclipse will not find ADT plugin on Mac

Tags: macos, plugins, adt

Eclipse will not recognise the ADT plugin on my Mac (running OSX 10.5.8.)

I have followed all instructions on the developers website:

1. installed Android SDK Tools, SDK platform Tools and Android 4.1 (API 16)
2. installed Eclipse Classic and restarted.

When going to Eclipse, Preferences, there is no option called Android

Can any one help?

I have already uninstalled and reinstalled everything and also tried different versions of eclipse, but this has still not helped

Answer (score 0):

You need to install the Eclipse plugin for Android options to show up in its preferences.
Just follow along the [official docs](https://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/installing-adt.html#Download) to install the plugin in Eclipse and get it to point to the sdk you've downloaded.